# SqlBulkCopy is slow, doesn't utilize full network speed

Tags: sql-server, database, networking, smo, sqlbulkcopy

for that past couple of weeks I have been creating generic script that is able to copy databases. The goal is to be able to specify any database on some server and copy it to some other location, and it should only copy the specified content. The exact content to be copied over is specified in a configuration file. This script is going to be used on some 10 different databases and run weekly. And in the end we are copying only about 3%-20% of databases which are as large as 500GB. I have been using the SMO assemblies to achieve this. This is my first time working with SMO and it took a while to create generic way to copy the schema objects, filegroups ...etc. (Actually helped find some bad stored procs).

Overall I have a working script which is lacking on performance (and at times times out) and was hoping you guys would be able to help. When executing the WriteToServer command to copy large amount of data (> 6GB) it reaches my timeout period of 1hr. Here is the core code for copying table data. The script is written in PowerShell.

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $selectedTable " + $global:selectiveTables.Get_Item($selectedTable)).Trim()
Write-LogOutput "Copying $selectedTable : '$query'"            
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand -argumentList $query, $source
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
$bulkData = ([Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy]$destination)
$bulkData.DestinationTableName = $selectedTable;
$bulkData.BulkCopyTimeout = $global:tableCopyDataTimeout # = 3600
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
$bulkData.WriteToServer($reader); # Takes forever here on large tables
```

The source and target databases are located on different servers so I kept track of the network speed as well. The network utilization never went over 1% which was quite surprising to me. But when I just transfer some large files between the servers, the network utilization spikes up to 10%. I have tried setting the $bulkData.BatchSize to 5000 but nothing really changed. Increasing the BulkCopyTimeout to an even greater amount would only solve the timeout. I really would like to know why the network is not being used fully.

Anyone else had this problem? Any suggestions on networking or bulk copy will be appreciated. And please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have tweaked several options that increase the performance of SqlBulkCopy, such as setting the transaction logging to simple and providing a table lock to SqlBulkCopy instead of the default row lock. Also some tables are better optimized for certain batch sizes. Overall, the duration of the copy was decreased by some 15%. And what we will do is execute the copy of each database simultaneously on different servers. But I am still having a timeout issue when copying one of the databases.

When copying one of the larger databases, there is a table for which I consistently get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

It is thrown about 16 minutes after it starts copying the table which is no where near my BulkCopyTimeout. Even though I get the exception that table is fully copied in the end. Also, if I truncate that table and restart my process for that table only, the tables is copied over without any issues. But going through the process of copying that entire database fails always for that one table.

I have tried executing the entire process and reseting the connection before copying that faulty table, but it still errored out. My SqlBulkCopy and Reader are closed after each table. Any suggestions as to what else could be causing the script to fail at the point each time?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[badTable](
[someGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[xxx] [int] NULL,
[xxx] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [datetime] NULL,
[xxx] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[xxx] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_badTable] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[someGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

No indexes exist for this table on the target DB.

Comment: 5,000 batch size seems low and unlimited too high I would suggest trying 50,000 to 100,000 batch size.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I set the batch size to 50000 but again nothing much changed. The network utilization still hovers at 1%. Looking through the log file, the time it takes to copy over large tables is still similar. Actually took longer for one of the tables whose rows contained large content. Also, I forgot to mention this before but the script itself is run on the server where the new database is being created.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with key/index settings on your target table.  So please post your table & index definitions.

Comment: I stopped creating the indexes for the tables before copying the data and now the data copy process is much quicker. Unfortunately, that one table still causes an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered removing indexes, doing the insert, and then reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a dataset and wonder if this would be faster:

```
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
bulkData.WriteToServer($ds.Tables[0])
```

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply, overall this method was slower. It used a lot more of the cpu, but the network utilization did reach 2.5% at times. Problem is that it wasn't a consistent 2.5% and was at 0 for long periods as well (during the disk write process?). I could probably play around with the batch size again but I think I will instead just try bcp to transfer the data. I have heard it should be faster.

Comment: Although using bcp starts out well (full use of network speed), the bcp command gradually slows down to almost a halt. This bcp command slows down considerably at while copying the last rows of large tables, and resets to full speed on new tables. I must be overlooking something in the sql database itselt. I heard having the tables clustered could cause such problems.

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulk Copy is by far the fastest way of copying data into SQL tables.
You should be getting speeds in excess of 10,000 rows per second.
In order to test the bulk copy functionality, try DBSourceTools. ( http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com )
This utility is designed to script Databases to disk, and then re-create them on a target server.
When copying data, DBSourceTools will first export all data to a local .xml file, and then do a Bulk Copy to the target database.
This will help to further identify where your bottleneck is, by breaking the process up into two passes : one for reading and one for writing.